# como enviar multiples strings en una func swift ios para una clase externa

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

Muy buen dìa. estoy intentando insertar en sqlite con swift por medio de una func: sin embargo me sale este error: **"Value of Type 'DataBaseHandler' has no member 'insertar_datos2'"**  ¿Cual serìa el error?

**NOTA: Ya he conectado las clases ej:   let numero_rows = DataBaseHandler().num_row_regs()
       status.text = String(numero_rows) y fuenciona correctamente**

```
    let junta = DataBaseHandler().insertar_datos2(add1: "hola", add2: "hola", add3:"hola")

print(junta)
```

**Y en  DataBaseHandler:**

```
func insertar_datos2(f1: String, f2: String, f3: String) -> String {

    databasePath = (NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("dires.db")

                let contactDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)

                if contactDB.open() {

    let insertSQL = "INSERT INTO CONTACTS (name, address, phone) VALUES ('\(f1)', '\(f2)', '\(f3)')"

    let result_insert = contactDB.executeUpdate(insertSQL,withArgumentsInArray: nil)

    if !result_insert {


         self.sucess = "Fallo Al Insertar Registro."
         print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")

                    } else {

                        self.sucess = "Listo. Insertado con Èxito"


                    }
                } else {
                    print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
                }


             return self.sucess

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estás llamando correctamente al método. La forma correcta sería:

```
let junta = DataBaseHandler().insertar_datos2("hola", f2: "hola", f3: "hola")
```

Además, no deberías de llamar a una función directamente al inicializarla. Es decir, la línea anterior sería más correcta de la siguiente manera:

```
let database = DataBaseHandler()
let junta = database.insertar_datos2("hola", f2: "hola", f3: "hola")
```

Por último, si tu clase manager no guarda ningún estado, te recomiendo usar métodos de clase para ello. Por ejemplo:

```
class DataBaseHandler {

    class func insertar_datos2(f1: String, f2: String, f3: String) -> String {

        //....

    }

}
```

De manera que, ahora sí, puedas utilizar el método directamente:

```
let junta = DataBaseHandler.insertar_datos2("hola", f2: "hola", f3: "hola")
```